# No wifi - Fedora 25 on Dell Latitude E5500

Tags: fedora, wifi, iwlwifi

No wifi - Fedora 25 - I googled around, tried few things and stumbled upon this:

I followed this [answer already](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/99042/no-wifi-in-fedora-25-new-to-fedora-and-linux/) ,
as well as some other suggestions mentioned in that post.

```
sudo dnf install -y https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-25.noarch.rpm https://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-25.noarch.rpm
sudo dnf install -y broadcom-wl kernel-devel
sudo akmods --force --kernel `uname -r` --akmod wl
sudo modprobe -a wl
```

When I get to this step: `sudo akmods --force --kernel`uname -r`--akmod wl`

I get:

```
 [ra170@localhost ~]$ sudo akmods --force --kernel `uname -r` --akmod wl

 Could not find files needed to compile modules for 4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64 
 Are the development files for kernel 4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64 or the appropriate kernel-devel package installed?
```

When I check if the devel kernel had been install I see:

```
 [ra170@localhost ~]$ rpm -qa | grep -e kernel-devel
```

Any ideas?
I've

```
    kernel-devel-4.11.0-0.rc1.git2.1.fc27.x86_64 
    kernel-devel-4.11.0-0.rc1.git3.1.fc27.x86_64
```

but when I check I get this:

```
[ra170@localhost ~]$ uname -r
4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64
```

any ideas? help!